# Problemas con metodos Date() javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de aprender a validar campos con js, pero por más que busco información tanto en Internet como por aquí no veo nada que me ayude a solucionarlo.
Necesito saber que la diferencia de fechas sea > 18 años.
En el codigo html, tengo un evento para ello.
Alguien me puede dar alguna pista . Gracias

```js
function validarFecha(){
     
var ahora = new Date();
var fIntroducida = new Date(introducida.value);
    
var introducida = document.getElementById('inputBirthDate').value;

var mesActual = ahora.getMonth()+1; //+1 empieza en 0
var diaActual = ahora.getDate();
var anoActual = ahora.getFullYear();   

var mesFor = fIntroducida.getMonth()+1; //+1 empieza en 0
var diaFor = fIntroducida.getDate();
var anoFor = fIntroducida.getFullYear();   
    
if (anoActual - anoFor >=18){
    if(mesActual > mesFor){
        return 1;
        
        if(diaActual >= diaFor){
        return 1;    
        }
   
    }
    
} else {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No veo a priori nada mal en tu función, salvo algún despiste quizás.
La variable "introducida":

```
var introducida = document.getElementById('inputBirthDate').value;
```

la has declarado despues de la variable "fIntroducida", la cual toma (necesita) el valor de la otra. No obstante, ten en cuenta que para que obtengas un objeto de tipo fecha válido, a no ser que le des un formato de tipo DD-MM-YYYY u otro, el formato adecuado debe ser YYYY-MM-DD (mira la fecha que he puesto como ejemplo).

Y solo te queda algún caso más que no has cubierto con else's. Por lo demas, todo ok.

Echale un vistazo al ejemplo.

Espero haberte ayudado.
Un saludo.

```js
validarFecha();
function validarFecha(){
     
var ahora = new Date();
var fIntroducida = new Date('2000-12-24');
    
//var introducida = document.getElementById('inputBirthDate').value;

var mesActual = ahora.getMonth()+1;
var diaActual = ahora.getDate();
var anoActual = ahora.getFullYear();

var mesFor = fIntroducida.getMonth()+1;
var diaFor = fIntroducida.getDate();
var anoFor = fIntroducida.getFullYear();

if (anoActual - anoFor >=18){

    if(mesActual >= mesFor){

        if(diaActual >= diaFor){
      document.write('mayor'); 
        }
        else{
         document.write('menor'); 
        }
   
    }
    else{
     document.write('menor');
    }
    
} else {
 document.write('menor'); 
}

}
```

O con varios ejemplos de hoy (24/11/2018):

```js
var fechas_ejemplo = ['2000-11-23','2000-11-24','2000-11-25'];
for(var i=0;i<fechas_ejemplo.length;i++){
 document.write('fecha'+(i+1)+': '+fechas_ejemplo[i]+' Resultado: ');
 validarFecha(fechas_ejemplo[i]);
 document.write(' | ');
}


function validarFecha(fecha){
     
var ahora = new Date();
var fIntroducida = new Date(fecha);

var mesActual = ahora.getMonth()+1;
var diaActual = ahora.getDate();
var anoActual = ahora.getFullYear();

var mesFor = fIntroducida.getMonth()+1;
var diaFor = fIntroducida.getDate();
var anoFor = fIntroducida.getFullYear();

if (anoActual - anoFor >=18){

    if(mesActual >= mesFor){

        if(diaActual >= diaFor){
      document.write('mayor'); 
        }
        else{
         document.write('menor'); 
        }
   
    }
    else{
     document.write('menor');
    }
    
} else {
 document.write('menor'); 
}

}
```

Para ponerla en el formato adecuado, si por ejemplo tu fecha tiene el formato dd/mm/yyyy:

```
var fecha_inicial = "24/11/2000";

var fecha_array = fecha_inicial.split("/"); //la conviertes en un array

var dateObject = new Date(fecha_array[2], fecha_array[1] - 1, fecha_array[0]); //la reordenas y la conviertes en un objeto date válido
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias, pero no se como establecer la fecha de hoy con ese formato, dentro de var ahora= new Date(), puedo establecer como parámetros, por así decirlo del tipo var ahora= new Date(anoActual,mesActual,diaActual) ? disculpa pero aún estoy aprendiendo, muchas gracias

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta. Última parte. De nada! :)